# Google Cloud SQL - syntax error on valid query

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to start app instance (Kubernetes engine in Google Cloud) which triggers some migration. Migrations are tested and work fine locally on Postgres 12. However, Google cloud Postgres (v11 as far as I understand) fails on query that looks totally valid for me.
I connected via PgAdmin over the Google Cloud Proxy to Google Cloud SQL and tried to execute migration query (create or replace procedure) and found the line that gives me the error. But, again, it looks totally correct to me and works locally, doesn't give any errors / suggestions in smart IDE, etc.
Error returned from the DB looks like

> QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "public"

The line that gives me this error is the second line from the code example below. Changing from `public.percent` to `percent` gives the same error ('syntax error at or near "percent"'). Replacing table with another table name gives the same error above. Replacing `UPDATE` with `SELECT` or with `RAISE NOTICE` or so (in test purpose) works fine.
Block of code that gives me this issue:

```sql
IF (update) THEN
  UPDATE public.percent
  SET percent = calculations[1]
  WHERE target_user_id = item.user_id
  AND type = secondary_criterion;
ELSE
  INSERT INTO public.percent (
    type,
    percent,
    target_user_id
  )
  VALUES (
    secondary_criterion,
    final,
    item.user_id
  );
END IF;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as simple as dumb. Since "update" is a reserved word all usages of it are vulnerable. Google cloud and Amazon somehow crush with this SQL. There is still an open question why it works locally on different stations, but at least the reason is clear.